# CakePhp3-ChartJs helper loading error

Tags: php, github, cakephp-3.0

ChartJs pluing form github and loaded using plugin  statement in bootstrap Plugin::load('ChartJs', ['bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => false]); and i tried to load this plugin's helper in appview  src\View\AppView.php like this

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadHelper('Html');
        $this->loadHelper('ChartJs.Chartjs');
    }
```

and pls find the image to know the plugin file structure
[image: pic one]
but is show error like ths when i load other pages

```
Fatal error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingHelperException] Helper class hartjsHelper could not be found. #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\ObjectRegistry.php(91): Cake\View\HelperRegistry->_throwMissingClassError('Chartjs', 'ChartJs') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(1002): Cake\Core\ObjectRegistry->load('ChartJs.Chartjs', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\src\View\AppView.php(44): Cake\View\View->loadHelper('ChartJs.Chartjs') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(336): App\View\AppView->initialize() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\ViewBuilder.php(350): Cake\View\View->__construct(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response), Object(Cake\Event\EventManager), Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\ViewVarsTrait.php(119): Cake\View\ViewBuilder->build(Array, Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dboard\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 156
```

guys pls help me to sort out ths issue and pls help me how to load helper on fly

Comment: `public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadHelper(['Html','ChartJs']); // or $this->loadHelper(['Html','ChartJs.chartjs']); 
    }`

Comment: hi Anant plugin name was not HTML ..plugin name is ChartJs tats y i tried with $this->loadHelper('ChartJs.Chartjs'); and this is $this->loadHelper('Html'); i tried to load inbuild html helper its works fine..but  this is not working $this->loadHelper('ChartJs.Chartjs');

Comment: My problem is ChartJsHelper can is not loading ..so am going to load it through autoload in composer.json